# Regex: match everythin from : until \n or <br />

Tags: php, regex

I would like to change the following text

```
тест: фыв, фыв <br />
тест: фыв, фыв, фывфыв фыв, фыв, фыв <br />
счет: 123 <br />
высота: 111 <br />
конец: ок <br />
```

to:

```
тест: :: фыв, фыв :: <br />
тест: :: фыв, фыв, фывфыв фыв, фыв, фыв :: <br />
счет: :: 123 :: <br />
высота: :: 111::  <br />
конец: :: ок :: <br />
```

what I've tried:

```
$text = <<<HTML
    тест<br /><br />тест: фыв, фыв<br />тест: фыв, фыв, фывфыв фыв, фыв, фыв<br /><br />счет: 123<br />высота: 111 <br />конец: ок<br /><br />
HTML;

$text = preg_replace('~(\w+:)\s*(.*?)(\<br /\>|\R)~', '\1 :: \2 :: \3', $text);

echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**RegEx:**](http://regex101.com/r/xT2wI2)

```
([^:]+:)\s*(.*?)(<br\s*/>|\R)
\1 :: \2 :: \3
```

---

**PHP**:

```
$row['text'] = preg_replace('~([^:]+:)\s*(.*?)(<br\s*/>|\R)~', '\1 :: \2 :: \3', $row['text']);
```

---

**Explanation:** First (`[^:]:`) we match and capture 1+ non-colon characters followed by a colon.  This is followed by some optional whitespace (`\s*`).  Then we [lazily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) capture 0+ characters (`.*?`).  Finally we capture either the line break (`<br\s*/>`) or the new line (`\R`).

**Notes:** I used `~` delimiters so that we didn't need to escape the `/` in the line break.  We use lazy repetition for the second capture group because it lets us grab everything *until* the line break or new line.

Comment: @Orlo I just went off your example with the `Something1:` etc, updated and should match cyrilic letters also.

Comment: that worked. but I'm experiencing another problem. I get randomly � at the end or beginning of some words. for example `Наджах` turns to `Наджа�`

Comment: `|\R` caused the problem. changing to `|\n` fix that.

Comment: I forgot `\R` "matches any Unicode newline sequence", so I bet some of the Unicode characters in your cyrilic letters were getting eaten up.